# Increasing the 150 character limit for the the Titles to allow proper description of math in the question.

Tags: feature-request, titles

a not too long math formulae's that are required to be in the title to make the referring links meaning full rather than having content like :
"Odd sum problem" , "Interesting integral question" etc. in the side referring links, one can see a nice summary of the question and what it really actually pertains.

So is it possible to have the 150 character limit not apply to mathjax? 
This is not really a feature request, just a request of relaxation of limit not to apply to math formulae's

Comment: I admit, I've had to lose unnecessarily specificity in a title because of this before.

Comment: The problem is that ignoring MathJax may lead to hacks $\textbf{in the form of MathJax text}$.